# How to upload and download a csv file to google drive using python?

Tags: python

can someone please help me. I need to know how to upload and download a csv file to google drive using python?

Answer (score 2):

Using **google collaborate**.

First you need to **mount** your drive and define the **PATH** to the directory where you want to download or store your files.

```
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/drive/')
PATH = "/content/drive/My Drive/..."
```

Finally I suggest you to use **pandas** library to download or save the file.

```
import pandas as pd

#Download
df = pd.read_csv(f"{PATH}file_name.csv")

#Save
df.to_csv(f"{PATH}file_name.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to run the script locally on my computer, does this library work with local Jypiter notebook or pycharm?

Comment: No it does not. As you can see it specific for google colab, it would not work if you work locally. Since you are working locally why don't you just download the .csv file? On the other hand I want to mention that google collaborate uses Notebook to run Python scripts, if you do not want/can't download the file I suggest you to use Google Collaborate. In my humble opinion it is the easiest way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google developer API to upload/download files to google Drive. This is the link to the help page with some code examples (dont forget you also have to enable the Google Drive API for you google account to be able to upload files.)

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#python